# Convert batch to one command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

How could i convert this batch file to a one command line?
It uses imagemagick commands to compare two bitmaps and get the match percentage.

I dont need the .txt logs created by it, i just need the final value displayed here:
echo Similar to  : %percentage% %%

```
compare 1f.bmp 1x.bmp -metric RMSE -subimage-search 2>diff.txt
set /P diff=<diff.txt


convert 1f.bmp -format "%%[fx:w*h]" info: >pixelcount.txt
set /P pixelcount=<pixelcount.txt
set /A percentage=100-((diff*100)/pixelcount)

echo Similar to  : %percentage% %% >pct.txt
```

Comment: The `&` is used to concatenate commands together on one line.

Comment: Ok i got it: compare 1f.bmp 1x.bmp -metric RMSE -subimage-search 2>diff.txt & set /P diff=<diff.txt & convert 1f.bmp -format "%[fx:w*h]" info: >pixelcount.txt & set /P pixelcount=<pixelcount.txt & set /A percentage=100-((diff*100)/pixelcount) & echo Similar to  : %percentage% % >pct.txt

Comment: How do avoid .txt to be created?

Comment: You said you need the percentage and that can't be calculated unless you capture the output of your commands.  So are you really asking **"How do I capture the output of a command without creating a text file?"**

Comment: If you want to pointlessly concatenate each command on the same line, you'll need to incorporate some methodology to delay variable expansion too.